# SQL Server - semicolon before THROW

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

As we know ending each statement with semicolon is a good practice. Let's assume we have some old code which uses `RAISERROR` to rethrow exceptions and we want to exchange it with `THROW`.

From: [`THROW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx):

> The statement before the **THROW** statement must be followed by the
>   semicolon (;) statement terminator.

Using only `ROLLBACK`:

```
BEGIN TRY
  -- some code
  SELECT 1;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  -- some code
  ROLLBACK
  THROW;
END CATCH
```

and we get **`Incorrect syntax near 'THROW'.`** which is perfectly valid.

But using `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` works without semicolon:

```
BEGIN TRY
  -- some code
  SELECT 1;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   -- some code
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   THROW;
END CATCH
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/578024)**</kbd>

Finally using `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION @variable`:

```
DECLARE @TransactionName NVARCHAR(32) = 'MyTransactionName';

BEGIN TRY
  -- some code
  SELECT 1;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   -- some code
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION @TransactionName
   THROW;
END CATCH
```

and once again we get **`Incorrect syntax near 'THROW'.`**.

Is there any particular reason why the second example works(backward compatiblity/...)?

---

**EDIT:**

There is great article written by Erland Sommarskog: **[Using ;THROW](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#jumpTHROW)**

Comment: what happens if you are some code after `THROW` instead of `;`?

Comment: @mcNets Do you mean something like [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/578031)?

Comment: Probably it is trying to rollback to a save point called throw.

Comment: @lad2025 yep, kinda wierd

Comment: According to MSDN docs: **Remarks
The statement before the THROW statement must be followed by the semicolon (;) statement terminator.**  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you alter the code so it actually throws an error.

```
BEGIN TRY
  -- some code
  SELECT 1/0;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   -- some code
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   THROW;

END CATCH
```

You see

> Msg 3903, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request
>   has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

It is trying to roll back to a save point called `THROW`.

This is valid syntax but fails at runtime in the above example as no transaction exists. If you are in an open transaction but have no such save point (as below)

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN
  SELECT 1/0;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   THROW;
END CATCH

ROLLBACK
```

you see the following instead.

> Cannot roll back THROW. No transaction or savepoint of that name was
>   found.

This kind of ambiguity is presumably why the requirement for a preceding semi colon before `throw` exists.